# UIApplicationDelegate but for each ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to get notified whenever a new view controller is shown, the UIApplicationDelegate provides such a way but for the whole app, not for each view controllers

Is there any delegate that is being called every time a new view controller appears?

#### Note

I totally aware of the functions inside UIViewController, but I am asking about a delegate separated from the View Controller itself, something like ApplicationDelegate

#### My Attempts

I searched a lot, the only solution that comes to my mind is to extend the ViewController, and then let my view controllers inherit this new view controller, but I would really prefer if there is a way to catch that events without changing anything in my view controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

method in `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Swift version:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

You can set your `UIApplicationDelegate` to be the delegate of the `UINavigationController` and get all the events there.

Comment: Thank you! your solution would work good, but I would have to create my custom UINavigationController

Comment: @WilliamKinaan not necessarily. Basically, your `viewControllers` are held inside a `navigationController`'s stack. You can access it from each one of them by `self.navigationController`. If you pass your `AppDelegate` to the first `viewController` you can assign it to be the delegate of the `navigationController` (`self.navigationController?.delegate = appDelegate`). You don't have to own the `navigationController` in order to use it that way.

Comment: What you've said is very interesting, indeed from the AppDelegate, I can catch the first view controller, and ask for its navigationcontroller, and then assign the delegate of the navigation controller. However, there are two things: First, what if the first view controller doesn't have any navigation controller? Then this `self.navigationController?.delegate` would have no effect. Second, what if you have many navigation controllers (thing of tab view controller in which each tab has its own navigation controller)

Comment: @WilliamKinaan it's hard to tell exactly what you need to do without knowing the entire architecture of your app. What I wrote in the previous comment is a general way to achieve what you need. I'm sure you will figure out the way to concentrate all the delegates into one class. A Singleton might be of use.

Comment: You have a very valid point, again!, the thing is I myself don't have a specific architecture, I'm  trying to build a solution that works with any architecture. Thanks for your time and efforts, I"ll accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself a delegate protocol, set the app delegate as the delegate for this protocol delegate and then in your view controller functions (`viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc) call your delegate function.

Comment: Thanks! But your solution requires extra work in each view controller

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a general solution for getting *notifications* or *delegate callbacks* when showing a given view controller across your app.

As already pointed out, you could get a partial solution when working only with a `UINavigationController`.